# Как узнать выполняется ли функция? и если да, то больше ее не запускать

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть блок с анимацией чисел, который запускается когда до него доскролил и больше не запускаться, но выходит так, что он запускается каждый раз, когда я до него до

```js
function playNumber(selector ) {
        
        const number = document.querySelector(selector);
        const time = 5000;
        const step = 2;
        let box = number.getBoundingClientRect();
        let isRun = false;
        function outNum(num) {
            let e = document.querySelector(selector);
            let n = 0;
            let t = Math.round(time / (num / step));
            let interval = setInterval(() => {
                n = n + step;
                if (n == num) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
                e.innerHTML = n;
            }, t);
        }
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            
            if (window.pageYOffset >= box.top + pageYOffset - document.documentElement.clientHeight + 100) {
                outNum(150);

              }   
            } 
        });
    }
        playNumber('.numberOne');
```

```html
<div class="service__info__inner__right__one">
                        <p class="service__info__inner__right__number"><span class="numberOne">0</span>%</p>
                        <p class="service__info__inner__right__text">увеличение прибылей при грамотном использовании соцсетей</p>
                    </div>
```

скролю. Как можно узнать, запустилась ли функция, и если да, то больше ее не запускать?

Comment: ну у вас же есть isRun. Пользуйтесь

Comment: Он есть, но я не знаю что делать

Comment: Очевидно в одном месте кода поставить true, и ещё в одном проверить то значение. а теперь подумайте где каждую операцию можно сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас уже есть флаг isRun, который можно использовать для проверки. Когда функция запуститься просто измените этот флаг.

```
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        
        if (window.pageYOffset >= box.top + pageYOffset - document.documentElement.clientHeight + 100 && !isRun) {
            outNum(150);
            isRun = true;
          }   
        } 
    });
```

Потом ещё желательно удалить слушателя с помощью removeEventListener

Comment: _«Потом ещё желательно удалить слушателя с помощью removeEventListener»_ - или передать `{ once: true }` третьим аргументом при вызове `addEventListener`: тогда слушатель автоматически удалится после обработки одного события.